# Using sed / awk to change words between two patterns

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I'm writing the shell script that should process through some text, I've got the text like that:

```
read build { file1 file2 file3 }
check build { file2 file3 file4 }
read build { file4 file5 file6 }
```

I want to add some text before all files - that means words, that are included between brackets in 'read build' lines, what do you think is the best idea to achieve that? The results should look like that:

```
read build { MY_ADDED_WORDfile1 MY_ADDED_WORDfile2 MY_ADDED_WORDfile3 }
check build { file2 file3 file4 }
read build { MY_ADDED_WORDfile4 MY_ADDED_WORDfile5 MY_ADDED_WORDfile6 }
```

I was trying with greping that lines, next parsing it to array and concatenate this "file" strings with the word I want to add, but I think that is not a "smart" solution. Thanks for your help.

Input files look like this:

```
set build { file1 file2 file3 file4 }
check $build

read build -new -f $build
read build -new -f { fileA fileB fileC fileD }

set build {file5 file6 file7 }

read build -old -f $build
read build -old -f { fileX fileZ fileD }

check_that_building
```

Output should look like that:

```
set build { file1 file2 file3 file4 }
check $build

read build -new -f $build
read build -new -f { MY_ADDED_WORDfileA MY_ADDED_WORDfileB MY_ADDED_WORDfileC MY_ADDED_WORDfileD }

set build {file5 file6 file7 }

read build -old -f $build
read build -old -f { MY_ADDED_WORDfileX MY_ADDED_WORDfileZ MY_ADDED_WORDfileD }

check_that_building
```

There is always a space before opening bracket but it can be a situation that there will be not a space after opening bracket, there can a space before closing bracket but it's not always.  Possible cases:

```
read build -old -f { fileX fileZ fileD }
read build -old -f {fileX fileZ fileD }
read build -old -f { fileX fileZ fileD}
read build -old -f {fileX fileZ fileD}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn’t immediately figure out how to do it in `sed`
without assuming that there is at least one character
that is known never to appear in the input. 
I assumed that `#` will never appear in the input (or in your added word). 
This seems to work:

```
sed '/read build/ {
        s/{/{ /
        : fruit
        s/\({.*\) \([^}# ][^ ]*\)/\1#MY_WORD\2/
        t fruit
        s/#/ /g
        s/{ /{/
}'
```

On lines that contain `read build`
it first inserts a space after the `{`.
Then it searches for a space that is somewhere after a `{`
and immediately before a word (presumably a filename). 
It replaces the space with `#`, inserts your word,
and goes back and looks for more. 
(`fruit` is an arbitrary loop label.) 
Once it’s found them all, it turns all the `#` characters back to spaces,
and removes the space that it inserted (after the `{`).

In addition to the bit about `#` not occurring in the input,
this assumes that

- `}` is the last non-blank character on each `read build` line, and
- whitespace is spaces only; no tabs.

---

In `awk`:

```
awk '/read build/ {
        in_braces=0
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
                if ($i == "{") in_braces=1
                else if (substr($i,1,1) == "{") {
                        $i = "{MYWORD" substr($i,2)
                        in_braces=1
                }
                else if ($i == "}") in_braces=0
                else if (in_braces) $i = "MY_WORD" $i
        }
      }
      { print }'
```

For each `read build` line,
it loops through all the words (fields) in the line. 
It uses a state variable (`in_braces`)
to keep track of whether it is between a `{` and a `}`;
if it is, it modifies each word to begin with your added word. 
Note that it has to handle two slightly different cases:

- if a word ***is*** `{`,
  set the flag to start modifying all subsequent words, and
- if a word *begins with* `{`, it is actually a compound of the form
  `{fileX`, so modify *it* to be the concatenation
  of `{`, the added word, and the *`fileX`* filename. 
  And also set the flag to modify all subsequent words.

While this allows tabs as word separators,
it has the weakness that it collapses white space to a single space. 
So for example, the input

```
read build    {    file1    file2    file3    }
```

would produce the output

```
read build { MY_WORDfile1 MY_WORDfile2 MY_WORDfile3 }
```

Further, this assumes that

- the `{` is at the beginning of a word (i.e., it has whitespace before it),
  and
- either `}` is the last non-blank character on each `read build` line,
  or it is a separate word (i.e., it has whitespace before and after)

It allows multiple sets of braces; e.g.,

```
read build { file1 file2 file3 } text to be left alone { file4 file5 file6 }
```